# how to separate array while parsing the json jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am parsing the json .Actually I need to find property from json. In my json I have two nested array (list, array).I need to get there separate value .But I am getting all value in an array can we split array "list" array in separate array   ."array" in separate array.
I am getting this out put :

**33, 44, 23, 11**
Here is my fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/f5Awq/

```
var arrayLabel=new Array();
var listLabel=new Array();

function recursiveIteration(object, callback, data) {
  for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if (typeof object[property] == "object"){
        recursiveIteration(object[property], callback, data);        
      }
      else {
        callback(object, property, data);
      }
    }
  }
}
function test_cb(object, property, data) { console.log(property);
  if(property == data.filter && object[property]){
    data.array.push(object[property]);
  }
}

recursiveIteration(json, test_cb, {filter: 'label', array: arrayLabel});

console.log(arrayLabel);

document.body.textContent = arrayLabel.join(', ');
```

I am getting out put in arrayLabel: **33, 44, 23, 11**

My expected out put :

**arrayLabel :33, 44.
   listLabel is 11,23**

33, 44 because they are in "array".and 11,23 in list in my json.can we add condition ?

Comment: because I need to get separate value .I need what label value in from which array ..in other word if I want to print all label properties which are only array(my json tag).it print only 11 ,23

Comment: nothing ever references `listLabel`. why do you expect it to become [11, 23]?

Comment: @quest you are right I need add condition ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope youneed this:

```
var arrayLabel = {'list':[],'array':[]};
var listLabel = new Array();

function recursiveIteration(object, callback, data,parent) {
    parent=parent||'root';
    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof object[property] == "object") {
                if (['list','array'].indexOf(property)>=0) {parent=property;} //the condion you looked for
                recursiveIteration(object[property], callback, data,parent);
            } else {
                callback(object, property, data,parent);
            }
        }
    }
}

function test_cb(object, property, data,parent) {
    if (property == data.filter && object[property]) {
        data.array[parent].push(object[property]);
    }
}
```

so, I recording the current "legal" parent name and accumulate it to data. You can easy make it an option.

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/f5Awq/1/